# MISRA-C Rule 11.2: conversion from array to pointer

Tags: c, casting, misra

I have two structs:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8 valid;
    uint8 identifier[20];
    uint8 parentIdentifier[20];
    /* etc */
} CustomData;

#define max_data_size 10
typedef struct {
    CustomData data[max_data_size];
    uint32 numberOfUsedData;
    /* etc. */
} MyContext;
```

and a function with the signature

```
uint8 parentInList(CustomData *data, 
                   const CustomData* const list,
                   uint32 length);
```

I try to call my function as follows:

```
MyContext ctx = /* some proper initialization */;
result = parentInList(&ctx.data[0], ctx.data, ctx.numberOfUsedData);
```

My static analysis to says that `ctx.data` is a cast violating rule 11.2 of MisraC:
"Conversions shall not be performed between a pointer to an
incomplete type and any other type"

However I can't see how this is incorrect. Arrays aren't an incomplete type if they have a fixed size right?
Is this my static analyzer giving a false positive because of the macro? Or have I made a mistake and how would I fix it?

Comment: `MyContext` is not a pointer type, so I don't understand how you use `->` with `ctx` which is not a pointer and getting it compiled.

Comment: `MyContext ctx` isn't initialized so that's a problem

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right. This is a simplified example, but my actual code compiles and behaves as expected, it's just a MISRA error. Edited the question.

Comment: @bigwillydos They are initialized in my actual code, this is a simplified example. I thought the comment would be explanatory.

Comment: Does `&ctx.data[0]` work?

Comment: I meant as the second parameter, but whatever.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ah, I misunderstood, I will test this an get back to you!

Comment: Most likely this refers to one of the structs being incomplete type. Meaning you are missing an `#include` or such. We can't really answer this without code that reproduces the problem. Copy/paste the actual code, including declarations and initializations.